# How do I heal Batfellow?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

So I am using the Batfellow comic, and I'm out of health. Usually in KoL I'd go back to my campsite and heal, but that doesn't really work in the comic adventure. I tried going back to my Bat-Cavern, thinking maybe I could heal there, but no dice.

How do I heal Batfellow so I can keep on fighting crime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Travel Downtown, and hit Gotpork General Hospital

Answer (score 1):

Go to downtown area then in chemicorp you can trade dangerous chemicals for Ultracoagulator. This can be used during battle and fully restores your HP, also, when you use it, the enemy waits a turn to attack you. Effectively, you can use the ulracoagulator then attack.